# Not able to find Application Class in new setup for couple of project in JellyBeans and new eclipse

Tags: android

I already had eclipse with android plugin and ICS. Sometimes i faced problem after updating to new version of ADT plugin. So to work with jellybeans (4.1), i downloaded and installed new android on different folder in programmeFile foder, and new eclipse(Juno Classic Version: 4.2.0) in different folder.  after configuring both i used same workspace for new eclipse which i was using for older eclipse. Now my two project which have external jar is not working in this eclipse. even though i crated new project from cvs yet also it is not working. and after crating project in new eclipse even though if i come in the old eclipse i am not able to run it. It is showing following exception.  The problem is it is not able to find my application class and it says could not initiate Application class because it could not find it but it already defined in manifest file. Other small example project do not have there own application class that may be one reason they are working fine. The exception is as follow. Any suggestion or help is welcome.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.muvee.vea.MveaApplication: ****java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**: com.kartik.MveaApplication**
07-12 09:43:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(6012): Caused by: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.kartik.vea.MveaApplication**
07-12 09:43:01.100: E/AndroidRuntime(6012):     at android.app.LoadedApk.mak
```

Answer (score 0):

Start your old eclipse with a new workspace, checkout your project into your new workspace and try to run it. Does it work?

Start your new eclipse with a new workspace, checkout your project into your new workspace and try to run it. Does it work?

Also did you say you installed the Android SDK twice? No need for that though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies on the following link. we need to specify external jar in Order and Import tab. You can refer [this link](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects) for more details.